# How configure and use doctrine extension? (doctrine2-spatial)

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I want use postrepgis in doctrine. I have find [creof/doctrine2-spatial](https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial) and I try use it. I have this error :

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 15 near 'ST_Contains(v.geopoint': Error: Class 'ST_Contains' is not defined.

I don't know why, I have read the documentation, I have try many differents configurations but alltimes same problem.

My config.yml

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver:   pdo_pgsql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    types:
        geometry:   CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\GeometryType
        point:      CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PointType
        polygon:    CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PolygonType
        linestring: CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\LineStringType

    mapping_types:
        _text: string
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    #naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    entity_managers:
        default:
            dql:
                numeric_functions:
                    ST_Contains:     CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\PostgreSql\STContains
                    Contains:     CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\PostgreSql\STContains
                    st_area:         CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\PostgreSql\STArea
                    st_geomfromtext: CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\PostgreSql\GeomFromText
                    st_intersects:     CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\PostgreSql\STIntersects
                    st_buffer:     CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\PostgreSql\STBuffer
                    point: CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\PostgreSql\STPoint
            auto_mapping: true
```

And my repository

```
 public function findPointIn(){
    $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder =  $queryBuilder->select('v')
                            ->where(
                                $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                                    sprintf("ST_Contains(v.geopoint  , v.geopoint)"),
                                    $queryBuilder->expr()->literal(true)
                                )
                            );

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation, your `numeric_functions` names in config.yml must be lowercase. Change to:

```
numeric_functions:
    st_contains:     CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STContains
    contains:     CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Contains
    st_area:         CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Area
    st_geomfromtext: CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\GeomFromText
    st_intersects:     CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STIntersects
    st_buffer:     CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STBuffer
    point: CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Point
```

Comment: You are right. I write with uppercase during my test for debug. It don't work with lowercase.

Comment: So, you find the solution or not?